# Help with geometric probability (with regards to span).

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

Suppose we have two non-parallel vectors in $\mathbb R^3$.

Now, if we were to randomly select another vector in $\mathbb R^3$, what is the probability that that new vector lies in the span of the first two vectors?

My intuition says that the probability is 0 (i.e. $\mathbb R^2$ is infinitely smaller than $\mathbb R^3$, ergo 0), but I'm not sure.

Comment: Well, sure....though you have to be clear what you mean by "randomly select(ing)" a vector.  If, say, you imagine that you are selecting a  unit vector, so you are choosing a vector by picking a point uniformly on the $2-$sphere, then your span is just a circle which has no area.

Comment: As lulu points out, this depends on your "randomly selected vector from $\mathbb{R}^3$." There exist distributions on $\mathbb{R}^3$ that assign a positive probability of lying in a specific plane, while there are others that assign zero probability to that event. A sufficient condition for your claim (zero probability) to hold is for the distribution to have a density on $\mathbb{R}^3$. However, this is not a necessary condition, as lulu's example demonstrates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to model this, so everything becomes finite is to work on the unit sphere $S^2$. We may assume that the hyperplane is $H=\{z=0\}\subset \mathbb{R}^3$. The probability that a random vector of $S^2$ doesn't lie on the great circle $H\cap S^2$ would be exactly
$$
\frac{|S^2\setminus (H\cap S^2)|}{|S^2|}= 1. 
$$

The only problem here is that we exclude the zero vector, but I assume that this is not a big deal. So, I would say your intuition is correct.